# Java EE Open Source project to learn from?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'am trying to dive deeper into Java EE,
so i was browsing [SourceForge](http://www.sourceforge.net) to look for a project 
that can help me see how  components fit together
so if comeone could point out a specific open source project
or any other resource that can help me with this.

Comment: JavaEE is a set of specifications, many of which you aren't likely to use together in the same project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The canonical sample application to learn Java EE used to be the Pet Store from the Java BluePrints program (now) at Oracle.

Check out [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/blueprints/index.html) for a list of blueprints. The Pet Store is [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/releases/petstore/)

Answer (score 2):

Barring a specific need, if I wanted to "learn Java EE" today, I would focus on the EJB-Lite profile of Java EE 6. Basically this is the web tier, JPA, and embedded Session Bean EJBs.

These components are the "90+%" of what folks do with a full boat Java EE server today. I don't consider learning the web tier enough to be considered "Java EE". Yea, it's a component of Java EE, but I think EJB is more important, and EJB is more "interesting" along with the web tier.

EJB-Lite hits the sweet spot of functionality and ease of deployment and packaging.

Answer (score 1):

[Open eSignForms](http://open.esignforms.com) by Yozons is an excellent Java EE application to learn on.

Check out their website and download their esignature and web contracting application.

You'll learn advanced topics such as sending and receiving mail, integrating with PostgreSQL, Apache Tomcat, encryption, and much more!

They also make extensive use of the Java framework Vaadin for a modern and responsive web application interface.